# Simple React router not working

Tags: react-router

Can't for the life of me get a simple react-router to work! It displays the first page, but when I click the link it doesn't do anything but change the url to /home. It keeps showing "app". Why is the home component not loading???

Simple code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'    

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div><Link to="/home">app</Link></div>
        );
    }
}    

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Honey, I'm home!!!</div>
    );
  }
}    

render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('tempoot')  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you haven't told it to render `Home` anywhere. You need to do something like (core thing you are missing is `{this.props.children}`):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'    

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="nav">
                <Link to="/home">app</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                // THIS IS THE CORE LINE YOU ARE MISSING
                {this.props.children || "No one is home :("}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}    

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Honey, I'm home!!!</div>
    );
  }
}    

render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <Route path="home" component={Home}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('tempoot')  
)
```